Direct quantum reduction from GapSVP to SIS
Looking through Chen's recent paper, if we forget about complex Gaussians and just build uniform superpositions over hypercubes, we could create the state
$$\sum_{v\in L}\vert v\rangle \sum_{y\in\mathbb{Z}^n:\Vert y\Vert_{infty}<R}\vert y\rangle$$
and measure $y'=y+v\bmod P$ and make some argument that this is
$$ \sum_{v\in L: \Vert y'-v\Vert_\infty < R}\vert y'-v\rangle$$
If we assume that $\lambda_2^\infty(L) > R > \lambda_1(L)$, then we can argue that there is some $y_0\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that, if $x$ is the shortest vector in the lattice, then the above state equals
$$ \sum_{k=-B}^B \vert y_0+kx\rangle$$
Taking the QFT of this state, modulo some $P\geq R$, gives us
$$ \sum_{z\in \mathbb{Z}_P^n} \vert z\rangle e^{2\pi i \langle y_0,z\rangle/P}\sum_{k=-B}^B e^{2\pi i k \frac{\langle x,z\rangle}{P}}$$
The sum over $P$th roots of unity should cancel out if $\langle x,z\rangle\approx 0\mod P$; as $B$ approaches $P$, the approximation will be closer. Or more directly, measuring $z$ gives us an equation
$$ \langle z,x\rangle + e\equiv 0\mod P$$
for small(ish) $e$. But we can do this as many times as we want, so we end up with a matrix $Z$ and a vector $E$ such that $Zx+E\equiv 0\mod P$, or $[Z | I](x,e)^T\equiv 0\mod P$. This looks just like an SIS problem, and if we solve it, we recover the shortest vector from the lattice.
(This is a bit hand-wavy, and maybe it should be $\langle x,z\rangle$ is approximately in $\frac{B}{P}\mathbb{Z}$, but the basic idea seems to be the same).
This seems much more direct than Regev's reduction to LWE. The condition that $\lambda_2^\infty(L)>\lambda_1(L)$ is somewhat restrictive, and it probably needs a more significant gap that will translate to the noise:modulus ratio of the SIS problem. Is this reduction well known? Is there some issue I've overlooked in it?

Is z uniform here? It looks less than 100% obvious to me that it is.

Ah, it is extremely not uniform. We could try doing $SX| I^T\equiv 0\mod P$ for uniform $S$, but that's not quite enough to create a general SIS instance.

@SamJaques Could you kindly include a link to Chen's paper? Thanks
